# Quit makefile if version is to old

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile using the .ONESHELL command. This feature is supported beginning from version 3.82 of Make.

Is there a way to check and exit if the Make version is to old ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ifeq ($(filter oneshell,$(.FEATURES)),)
$(error Your version of make does not support .ONESHELL)
endif
```